# Can you reproduce results of VRP?

Tags: or-tools

If I am using, say guided local search for a VRP, I keep getting slightly different results even when I set a seed to generate my data. Is this normal because it is a heuristic and not an algorithm or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal, and yes it is because it uses heuristics, not a "real" optimization since VRP is an NP-hard problem. Even if you run it on a different system that has different hardware configurations, especially the CPU, there is a possibility that it will produce different results. Everything depends on how complex is the VRP problem, the more complex the problem the probability of producing different results will increase.